# Javascript Array to CSV on Beaglebone black

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, beagleboneblack

I have the following comma separated 2D array in javascript that I am trying to save as its own file in a separate folder on a BeagleBone Black board.

```
data = [['Date','Number'],['Mar012015',25],['Mar022015',32]];
```

The first entry (['Date','Number']) are the column titles. The array can vary in length.

The code is currently running in the "autorun" folder and I would like to save it in a folder I made called "data" in the same directory. The only documentation I can find on this deals with HTML which I am not using.

Comment: You could generate simple csv content like this `var csv_content = data.map(function(v){return v.join(',');}).join('\n\r');`

Comment: I already have the csv content I just want to save it as a file into a specified folder on the drive.